# RxJS: Combining two http.get() to one object

Tags: json, wordpress, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm using [WP Rest API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) to access my Wordpress database with Angular 2. I use their [post API](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/) and return a json object which I map to create an object.

Object:

```
export class BlogPost {
    date: Date;
    id: number;
    link: string;
    title: string;
    author: number;
    excerpt: string;
    featuredMediaURL: string;
    featuredMediaID: number;
    categories: string[];
    tags: string[];


    constructor(obj?: any) {
        this.date               = obj && obj.date               || null;
        this.id                 = obj && obj.id                 || null;
        this.link               = obj && obj.link               || null;
        this.title              = obj && obj.title              || null;
        this.author             = obj && obj.author             || null;
        this.excerpt            = obj && obj.excerpt            || null;
        this.featuredMediaURL   = obj && obj.featuredMediaURL   || null;
        this.featuredMediaID    = obj && obj.featuredMediaID    || null;
        this.categories         = obj && obj.categories         || null;
        this.tags               = obj && obj.tags               || null;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
export class BlogService {
    constructor(public http: Http,
                @Inject(DOMAIN) private domain: string) {  }

    getPost(): Observable<BlogPost[]> {
        return this.http.get(`${this.domain}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?page=1`)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                return (<any>response.json()).map(item => {
                    return new BlogPost({
                        date: item.date,
                        id: item.id,
                        link: item.link,
                        title: item.title,
                        author: item.author,
                        excerpt: item.excerpt,
                        featuredMediaID: item.featured_media,
                        categories: item.categories,
                        tags: item.tags
                    });
                });
            });
    }
```

My problem is that for certain properties such as media, the API returns an ID for the media and not the url. I was able to mix and match and get the url into the template by creating a separate service which returns all media stored on the database and then compares the id numbers between the two arrays and returns the correct one:

```
mediaURL(id: number): string {

    for (let med of this.media) {
        if(med.id === id) {
            return med.url;
        };
    };
    return 'error';
}
```

but this is a bit tedious. I was wondering if there is a clean rxjs way to do this by issuing a

```
this.http.get(`${this._domain}/wp-json/wp/v2/media/<id>`)
```

line and mapping it to the BlogPost.featuredMediaURL before the whole array of posts is returned to the blog component.

I've messed around with it for a day trying several things and I'm at a loss.

Comment: Where is this `mediaURL` function used in the context of the above code block? What is id? Is it the `featureMediaID`?

Comment: @paulpdaniels mediaURL is in the component and is called in the template with `{{ mediaURL(b.featuredMediaID) }}`. So correct, `id` is `featuredMediaID` from the `BlogPost` class.